# invoke SSL on betfair.py

Tags: python, api, ssl, betfair

I've been looking to plug into the Betfair api via [betfair.py](https://github.com/jmcarp/betfair.py).

I'm completely stuck at the 'invoke ssl' part. I've tried it via the anaconda command line and it seems to just timeout indefinitely. Feel like I’m missing something completely obvious in where I should be calling this (is it even on the command line? Did try also calling it in various guises in a Jupyter notebook but looking at the errors pretty sure that’s not correct), and have googled it to death but can’t find anyone else with the same issue.

What (incredibly obvious no doubt) thing am I missing?

Comment: I was able to use the instructions found [here](http://www.bespokebots.com/betfair-ssl-certs.php) to create the certificates instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the types.py file. If you checkout the betfair api out via git (or download a zip) you will find a types.py file in the root directory and you'll be able to run the invoke ssl command. If you installed via pip then I don't think this file is brought down.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make own certs via OpenSSL which work fine, obviously still curious about the original question if anyone has an answer.